# Batch script having weird issues when put on Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Batch script that is using psftp to get files from a Linux server

//test.bat

```
@echo off
echo "starting script" >> test.txt
echo y | "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\psftp.exe" user@server.com -b C:\runCmds.bat
exit
```

// runCmds.txt

```
cd /this/directory
lcd C:\directory
mget ./*.complete
mget ./*.zip
quit
```

This is an extreamely stripped down version, but it is the basis of the issue that I'm having. My entire batch file, complexity and all will run flawlessly if I run it manually. My Scheduled Task will run successfully, as there are no errors and the test.txt log file will display the text I set up. I've seen some issues with scheduled tasks and double quotes, but I'm not sure if this is the issue. Looks like the psftp command isn't working correctly. This is on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: put your 3rd line into parantheses and add a `>>test.txt` like this: `(echo <...>\runCmds.bat)>>test.txt`. Any errors?

Comment: good call. So it promopted for my password a couple times, and I an using a private_key. So the task is set to use SYSTEM to run it, maybe it doesn't have access to my key? I confirmed that it works with my username and password. Anyway to make the SYSTEM aware of my private key? That's what the problem looks like to me anyways. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: I have pageant loading up "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pageant.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\private_key.ppk" which is supposed to start pageant and load the private key, however the logs are outputting "user's password:" several times. So it looks like it's not using they key...

Comment: Task scheduler uses the system account by default, which doesn't have network privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the comments led me to the following solution.

I was using SYSTEM to run the Scheduled Task, which did not have access to my private_key. I updated this to use Administrators who is the owner of the private_key file. Then, instead of loading pageant with the private key, I used the -i parameter to specify the private_key. All works well now. Thanks!

// test.bat

```
@echo off
echo "starting script" >> test.txt
echo y | "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\psftp.exe" user@server.com 
    -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\private_key.ppk" -b C:\runCmds.bat
exit
```